# How do I get the ! (exclamation point) beside wifi / network connection on emulator to appear so I can troubleshoot a bug

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to troubleshoot a bug that I think is related to firebase push notifications or parses push notification service that causes an ANR crash when my app starts up before I even do anything.

It only occurs when I have a bad connection state with wifi or network when there's an exclamation point beside the network status

Specifically when it looks like this

[image]

Is there some command I can use to cause this state so I can trouble shoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any command but it should be easy to replicate.
That's the state that the device is connected, but it failed to detect that the network has access to the internet.

So to replicate this:

- turn off mobile data
- connect to WiFi
- on the WiFi router, disconnect the cable from the internet provider (e.g. ADSL is a phone cable)

Comment: At home it looks like that might work, but I'm not getting the same ANR (although it is hanging.... so maybe it's device specific with the ANR and I can't check at home) but the bigger issue is - I can't disconnect the entire wifi at work while working on this.  I still need a way to do it there, or maybe convince them I need to work from home for the day if it really is properly reproducing the bug

Comment: There are other ways. You can create an access point from a normal PC or from another device, and cut the internet from that access point.