# Android - How to know the Wi-Fi icon status with the Exclamation mark programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing an Android app. 
I have a logic to make certain action work only while the WiFi internet connection is working properly.

So I'd like to exclude the state of WiFi icon with an exclamation mark.

Is there a programmatic way to find out if the WiFi icon has the exclamation mark?

[image: WiFi icon with Exclamation mark]

Comment: This answer may help you find the answer to your own question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52174564/8040697

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I USB debug a device and block that device's outgoing traffic from my router, I can consistently get the Wi-Fi exclamation mark to show up on my device.

Debugging the `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.onCapabilitiesChanged` event, I've found that the magic marker flag you want which is 100% always tied to that exclamation mark displaying, is the `NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED` capability.

If it's not validated, you get the exclamation mark.